# Reassignment is ignored by the interpreter

Tags: python

The following code is a testing part for two functions that convert between hexadecimal and binary numbers, both receiving and returning strings:

```
hex_list = []
for i in range(50):
    hex_list.append("0X" + "".join([random.choice("0123456789ABCDEF") for j in range(10)]))
for index, hex in enumerate(hex_list):
    iterations = 0
    while hex_list[index][2] == "0":
        print(f"ENTERING LOOP FOR ZERO AT THE LEFT IN {hex}")
        print("BEFORE ", hex_list[index])
        hex_list[index] = hex[:2] + hex[3:]
        print("AFTER ", hex_list[index])
        iterations += 1
        if iterations > 5:
            print("\n5 ATTEMPTS REACHED FOR {hex}\n")
            break
```

I don't know why, but in some cases, the while falls into an infinite loop because the hex_list[index] element remains the same besides the reassignment instruction. Any idea on why?

The conditional that controls the iterations variable and that variable itself control that the loop exits so I can see the output in detail.

Comment: I realized that I used the reserved name "hex". Does that also affect the result?

Answer (score 1):

When you start looping, `hex` and `hex_list[index]` are references to the same string. However, after the first reassignment to `hex_list[index]` they stop being the same. `hex` remains a reference to the original string, while `hex_list[index]` is the new string you made by concatenating two slices from the original. This means that if the loop keeps going, you will keep remaking the same new string over and over again, since you're slicing from `hex`, and it never changes.

There are a few ways you could fix this. One is to make the inner loop change `hex` rather than `hex_list[index]`, and only assign the final value back at the end:

```
for index, hex in enumerate(hex_list):
    while hex[2] == "0":
        hex = hex[:2] + hex[3:]
    hex_list[index] = hex
```

Another option could be to skip `hex` entirely, and just loop over indexes directly. The the inner loop can operate directly on `hex_list[index]` all the time:

```
 for index in range(len(hex_list)):
    while hex_list[index][2] == "0":
        hex_list[index] = hex_list[index][:2] + hex_list[index][3:]
```

If your values were lists, rather than strings, you could modify a value in place (by deleting an element), rather than making a value on each iteration. This isn't as advantageous as it sounds, as deleting a value from the middle of a list is pretty costly, taking O(N) time, similar to copying the list:

```
for inner_list in hex_list:
    while inner_list[2] == "0":
        del inner_list[2]
```

That's quite nice in its clarity, even if it isn't likely to be much better performing. If you wanted to go this direction, you could skip the `join` call you do in your setup loop and just append the list comprehension you do with `random.choice` to the outer list. You could format up the strings at the end.

If you wanted to get a bit more sophisticated, you could search for the first non-zero value, and chop all the zeros out in a single step, rather than doing it one by one. But that's a sufficiently larger task that I didn't want to mix it in here.

Comment: Oh, crud, that last option won't work then. The first two will. Let me edit to be clearer...

Comment: Good save, moving the join down, as they do really have lists early on. That said, it would be much simpler to keep their join where it is and do an `lstrip("0")` on it (before prepending `"0X"`). Then that's already the desired result. (Assuming the limiting to five iterations isn't intended and was just for debugging.)